# Is there any way to connect more then one PPC to ActiveSync?

Tags: windows-mobile, activesync

Is there any way to connect more then one PPC to ActiveSync

in one Computer ?

(that i can work on 2 PPC as parallel)

thank's in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Active sync is a PC connection to one device only.

You can setup a virtual machine - that is one PC, but two OSes.